# Bootstrap/jQuery form Validation with ASP.NET - Very Basic Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm an experienced .NET developer, and am "getting there" with jQuery and Bootstrap. I'm attempting to integrate jQuery form validation (jquery.validator.js add-on), and can't seem to get the basics in place. I feel like I'm doing exactly what the documentation specifies in order to make a basic example work, but I'm obviously missing something.

Here's my **page includes:**

```html
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/site-style-main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/site-script-step1validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's the **relevant HTML** pertaining to one of the fields to be validated, and the form:

```html
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Step1.aspx?RecertID=1" id="aspnetForm" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">First Name</span>
      <input name="ctl00$PageContent$RecertVFCFormView$ProviderFirstName" type="text" maxlength="256" id="ProviderFirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
  <a id="ExitButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$PageContent$RecertVFCFormView$StepController$ExitButton&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" aria-hidden="true"></i> Exit
  </a>
  
</form>
```

And here's what my jQuery looks like (site-script-step1validate.js):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#ProviderMedLicenseExpiration').datepicker();

 $('#aspnetForm').validate({

  onsubmit: false,
  rules: {
   ProviderFirstName: {
    required: true
   }
  },
  highlight: function (element) {
   $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
  }

 });

 $('#ExitButton').click(function (e) {

  var isValid = $('#aspnetForm').valid();

  if (!isValid) {
   e.preventDefault();
  }

 });

});
```

At this point my expectation is simply that without that first name field populated, the form will fail to submit; it does not. I know that my ExitButton.click function is being reached and that isValid winds-up as true.

Seems pretty straight-forward and I can't quite make-out what I'm missing. Likely something very simple.

Comment: Have you checked `isValid` returned by `valid`? May be connected or not but you shouldn't base your submit logic on button click handler. There are other ways to submit a form not including a click. I recommend you to use `$('#aspnetForm').submit(function(){...})`

Comment: Yes, as stated above, the isValid value ends-up as true when the button is clicked. I agree that using a button click event isn't necessarily preferred, but it's what was presented as a working example in some documentation I found on how to use validator with ASP.NET.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ProviderFirstName` rule must match with the name of the input control you're trying to validate. If you check the HTML you'll see that name is `ctl00$PageContent$RecertVFCFormView$ProviderFirstName`. Because of this the rule is just ignored.

A possible solution if you're using asp.net 4+ is to define [`ClientIDMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `TextBox` control as `static` to avoid .net engine to change the id based on parent container.

Another option that may goes against your training purposes is adding `required` to `TextBox` markup and remove the custom rule `ProviderFirstName`. It would have the same end result and definitively would make more sense on a real scenario.

Comment: I thought that the item to be matched was id, not name. I alraedy do have ClientIDMode set to Static, and the input ID is indeed ProviderFirstName. Are you saying that the rules look for the field's "name" property, not ID?

Comment: @MichaelDoleman: I believe that's the problem. Do a simple test: change the name of your rule to `ctl00$PageContent$RecertVFCFormView$ProviderFirstName`

Comment: I'll be damned. Yeah, that's it exactly. That surprises me, honestly. I'd have thought that it would be tied to ID, but no.

Comment: @MichaelDoleman: if you look for `rules` on [source code](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js), you'll see that `element.name` is always used. It is sad that setting `static` to `ClientIDMode` is not enough